# How to show image on when clicked that image

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to show the image when I click on that invisible image, I have used attributes of `setVisiblity` and `setAlpha` but still it's not working .

```
ImageView finger_a, finger_b,finger_c, finger_d;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_fingers);

    finger_a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_finger_A);
    finger_b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_finger_B);
    finger_c = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_finger_c);
    finger_d = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_finger_d);

    finger_a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finger_a.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Comment: You can set the android:src ="@null" and android:visibility = "visible" initially and set the image source when you click on the image

Comment: are those "`INVISIBLE`" images clickable??

Comment: at first image is invisible, i just want if i click on that image it should visible then.

Comment: `if(arg0 instanceof ImageView && arg0.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) arg0.setVisisbility(View.VISIBLE); else Log.e("OnClick", "Something went wrong");`

Comment: hey if that image is invisible then how you can click on that image :p :p

Comment: invisible image cannot be clicked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embed it in a linear layout and set the onClickListener on the linear layout. I don't think an invisible view is enabled for clicking.